# show specific country in shipping and all country in billing field woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in woocommerce check out page i want to show all countries in billing details field and show only specific country in shipping details country fields how i can do that

Comment: i just do this now. please check out image below answer and follow steps.

Answer (score 1):

[woocommerce setting  page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zllqD.png)

you can add from dashboard too.
ship to specific counties option to add specific countries.
no need to add code. use code when you need cause of already country code in woocomerce plugin.

i hope this help 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hook "woocommerce_checkout_fields" use to modify checkout fields.

```
function woo_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) { 

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Selected Country List', 'woocommerce'),
        'options'   => array('IND' => 'India','US' => 'USA')
    );

    return $fields; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'woo_override_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

No code needed. This can be done from Woocomemrce settings->General. Select "Sell to all countries" for "Selling Locations" and select the specific countries you want to ship to for "Shipping locations". See example below -

[image]